# Serialize Json with List<Map..> into custom object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, hashmap, deserialization

I have a custom object that has a handful of properties and even has other objects. It also has a List<Map<String, String>> that I am trying to deserialize from json using Jackson and the Object mapper using only annotations.

My Custom object looks like this,

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "CustomId",
        "Attributes"
})

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class MyCustomObject {

    public MyCustomObject(){
    }

    @JsonProperty("CustomId")
    private String customId;

    @JsonProperty("Attributes")
    private List<Map<String, String>> attributes;

    @JsonProperty("CustomId")
    public String getCustomId() {
        return customId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("CustomId")
    public void setCustomId(String customId) {
        this.customId = customId;
    }

    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = MapSerializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("Attributes")
    public List<Map<String, String>> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Attributes")
    public void setAttributes(List<Map<String, String>> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

Here are 3 examples of what the json response might look like,

```
{
    "CustomId": "9610",
    "Attributes": {}
}


{
    "CustomId": "9610",
    "Attributes": {
            "Test": 0
        }
}

{
    "CustomId": "9610",
    "Attributes": {
            "Test1": 3,
            "Test2": 4
        }
}
```

This is line I am using to parse the json and where my error occurs.

```
String result = (... A returned Json string);
strategy = objectMapper.readValue(result, new TypeReference<MyCustomObject>() {});
```

Lastly, the error I am receiving.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token....
....[truncated 270 chars]; line: 1, column: 768] 
 (through reference chain: com.model.jackson.MyCustomObject["Attributes"])
```

Are there any annotations I am missing? Are there any other examples out there of parsing into a list<map...>> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON object you have `Attributes` is an object (Map) but in your `MyCustomObject` class you trying to convert it to an array (List). So because of that you getting error.

Please change `private List<Map<String, String>> attributes;` to `private Map<String, String> attributes;` Remove list then check it will convert data successfully.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"CustomId", "Attributes"})

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class MyCustomObject {

    public MyCustomObject() {}

    @JsonProperty("CustomId")
    private String customId;

    @JsonProperty("Attributes")
    private Map<String, String> attributes;

    @JsonProperty("CustomId")
    public String getCustomId() {
        return customId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("CustomId")
    public void setCustomId(String customId) {
        this.customId = customId;
    }

    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = MapSerializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("Attributes")
    public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Attributes")
    public void setAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```